# Why the code below does not assert?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

[On this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c++/lNcpVmP24hc/Kj9bQ_vzscwJ) on comp.std.c++, Mr. Howard Hinnant shows the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

struct A
{
    A() : data_(1) {}
    A(A&& a) : data_(a.data_) {a.data_ = 0;}
    int data_;
};

void g(const A&) {}
void g(A&& a) {a.data_ = 0;}

void h(const A&) {}
void h(A&& a) {a.data_ = 0;}

void f(A&& a)
{
      g(a);  // calls g(const A&)
      h(a);  // calls h(const A&)
      if (true)
      {
          h(a); // calls h(A&&) (by Alexandrescu rules)
      }
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    f(a);
    assert(a.data_ == 1);
}
```

Then he writes:

> By the N1377 rules, it does not assert. ...

With the actual C++11 rules the code above doesn't compile because the lvalue `a` in `main()` doesn't bind to an rvalue reference. But just assuming it compiled, as probably was supposed to the case when this discussion occurred, I can't understand the assertion above, that is, `By the N1377 rules, it does not assert.`. According to the prior rules, wouldn't the variable `a` be pilfered (a.data_ = 0), as `a` is passed as an argument to `f` with f(a) ?

Comment: I have no idea why the rules were as such by that time, but woah that looks weird

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2831.html#changes

Comment: That's a *really old* source. The design of the language underwent many variations. Is this really relevant? Would you rather care to ask a question about C++11?

Comment: I was just trying to follow the discussion and was stuck with this problem.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.  `f(a)` expects, an rvalue reference, but `a` is not an rvalue. You'd need to do `f(std::move(a))` for this to compile, and after that, the state of `a` after the return of f is indeterminate.

Comment: @NathanErnst You certainly didn't read the last part of my question. But why do you say the state of a is indeterminate with std::move(a)?

Comment: @411165, See ISO/EC 14882-2012: §17.6.3.1, Table 20: "rv’s state is unspecified [ Note:rv must still meet the requirements of the library component that is using it. The operations listed in those requirements must work as specified whether rv has been moved from or not. —end note ]"  Note that "rv" in the case is the source instance of a move operation, and the above quote is on the post condition of a move assignment/construction.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++0x standard, a && declaration referred specifically to an r-value reference.  The link in the comments is good, as well as this link, referencing the 2006 version.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html

You can also find in depth discussion on the issue, and why it matters here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html

In short, rvalue references removes the need for the following idiom:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 1000;

//Now let's swap them
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

rvalue references allow for idioms that do not involve creating the temporary object, and using 50% more memory.  Though, even on the old standard where we care about the difference between A& and A&&, if you write reasonable code, the use of rvalue references dissapears, as the benefits can be easily optimized away in the standard code by any decent compiler.

I honestly do not know why the h(a) call changes to an rvalue reference because it is being called within the scope of an if statement.

EDIT: per the comments.

It was being propsed that the final use of a variable within the that variables scope should default to the rvalue version, as this is more optimal, and the pilfering that can be caused by such a reference does not matter, as the variable is soon to be out of scope.

So, the const A& version is slower than the A&& version.  Even though the const A& is a more concise type match, the A&& version is faster, and the dangers of using this are non-existant for the last reference of a an lvalue. Alexandrescu is proposing that, for such a "final reference" we use the rvalue.

However, Hinnant is stating that(through comments), under Alexandrescu's recommended modifications, the code does not do what is expected and the assertion is thrown, but under the current n1377 rules, with standard bindings, it does not.  Debunking his proposed change to the standard.

Hinnants example shows that this is a micro optimization, and that the rule needs to be much more consise than Alexandrescu suggests.  And that, because we can also pass lvalues around by reference, the times when you can use such rvalue references safely, is ultimately only once per declaration of a variable, a minor optimization at best.

Comment: `I honestly do not know why the h(a) call changes to an rvalue reference because it is being called within the scope of an if statement.` This was the change that Mr. Alexandrescu was proposing to the language in his first post (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c++/lNcpVmP24hc/SwiJkEMjmbEJ) on the same thread referred above.

Comment: Excellent reference, and I believe completes this answer nicely.